# Looking for a good Cassandra GUI Client Tool

Tags: cassandra

Kindly suggest a good client GUI tool for Cassandra or Please Share the download link of the DataStax DevCenter old version (V1.6.0). Currently we are using cqlsh to connect Cassandra. I couldn't find a better GUI for Cassandra.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3):

Found (and tested) description how to connect using only open-source via DBeaver:
https://javaresolutions.blogspot.com/2018/04/opensource-db-ui-tool-for-cassandra-db.html

1. Download dbeaver (Community Edition)
2. Download cassandra jdbc jar files: http://www.dbschema.com/cassandra-jdbc-driver.html (`Downloading and Testing the Driver Binaries` section have links to binary and source)
3. extract cassandra jdbc zip
4. run dbeaver
5. go to Database > Driver Manager
6. click New
7. Fill in details as follow:

   - Driver Name: Cassandra (or whatever you want it to say)
   - Driver Type: Generic
   - Class Name: com.dbschema.CassandraJdbcDriver
   - URL Template: jdbc:cassandra://{host}[:{port}][/{database}]
   - Default Port: 9042
   - Embedded: no
   - Category:
   - Description: Cassandra (or whatever you want it to say)
8. click Add File and add all of the jars in the cassandra jdbc zip
9. click Find Class to make sure the Class Name is found okay
10. click OK
11. Create New Connection, selecting the database driver you just added

Comment: DBeaver latest version does not support cassandra anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the only open source and running example I found
https://github.com/Kindrat/cassandra-client for ready to run jar, you can use https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/cassandra-client/releases/download/v0.0.0/cassadra-client-0.0.0-0-exec.jar I built in my linux mint, GUI looks little bit demo like but I connected to my local cassandra and saw a table and data in the UI.

Not open source options below, I tested 2 of them and they are working, I can suggest datagrip which works fast and nice.

- https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/download/#section=linux
- https://www.mongodbmanager.com/download <<-- idi not test this one
- https://razorsql.com/download.html

Answer (score 0):

You may also look to the [Cassandra interpreter in the Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-preview2/interpreter/cassandra.html).  The upcoming 0.9.0 release (0.9.0-preview2 is already available) contains [a lot of changes](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/new-functionality-of-cassandra.html) in supporting Cassandra.